# Isn't there a preposition ("to") missing after "IP addresses that devices are allocated"?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, passive-voice

I was looking through the [bregman-arie/devops-exercises](https://github.com/bregman-arie/devops-exercises) repository on GitHub when I saw this question:

> What is APIPA?

...with this answer:

> APIPA is a set of IP addresses that devices are allocated when the main DHCP server is not reachable

So, here is the question: isn't there the prep. "to" missing after the word "allocated"?

**P.S.** I've seen a lot of English text on the net that confused me with missing (at least, seemingly to me) prepositions used with passive voice verbs. Is forgetting a preposition after a verb is just a common mistake in English or I somehow missunderstand the rule by which prepositions should be placed in passive voice?

Comment: In that sentence, the IP addresses are given to the devices. If you wrote it "addresses that devices are allocated to" that would mean the devices are designated as belonging to the addresses instead of the addresses belonging to the devices... The active voice would be "The server allocates a set of IP addresses to the devices". I don't have time to write a complete answer right now, but I hope that helps a little.

Comment: Devices are allocated an IP address. [The grammar is fine]. It doesn't need to. But, if you make it fully passive, it becomes: IP addresses are allocated to devices. [However, the explanation is not great]. So, the text you found is grammatically correct. The verb allocate does not require to all the time.

Comment: @Lambie So based on your "fully passive" sentence, the definition could be reworded *APIPA is a set of IP addresses that are allocated to devices when the main DHCP server is not reachable* That seems a lot clearer than the original, although after reading a bit, the entire definition seems a bit suspect. "Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA) is a feature in operating systems (such as Windows) that enables computers to automatically self-configure an IP address and subnet mask when their DHCP server isn’t reachable."

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, right and yes, suspect and yes to that final quote.

Comment: In any event it's "technical English" with conventions that might not match non-technical expectations (e.g. rigorous usage of "SHALL" etc.). It might be clearer if expressed as something like "APIPA is a set of IP addresses from which a device may select when a DHCP server is not reachable". However, RFC 3927 is definitive: APIPA is strictly a Microsoft term from their "Embrace, Extend, Extinguish" era.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, definitely suspect. APIPA is not "a set of IP addresses". Rather, the RFC allocates IP addresses (from the set of all addresses), *for* devices to use when no DHCP server is available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a *potential* difference in meaning depending on whether we explicitly specify the preposition in contexts like the OP's example.

> *a set of IP addresses that devices are allocated [to]*

With ***to***, it means ***devices** are allocated **to addresses***, but *without* the preposition it means ***addresses** are allocated **to devices***. In practice, because of the "one-to-one" nature of the assignments between *inanimate* elements, this is a "notional" difference that doesn't really affect the meaning. But with a *slightly* different example, the difference becomes crucial. Consider...

> *We studied the plantations that slaves were **given** [**to**]*

...where the present or absence of ***to*** completely *reverses* the meaning. With ***to***, it means the slaves were given / assigned to *work* on the plantations. But *without* the preposition, it means that the plantations were given to the slaves. It's obviously less likely, but I'm sure at least *sometimes* slaves were given ownership of the place where they were previously *forced* to work.

Comment: People don't seem to care so much any more about the old rule that sentences should not end with prepositions, but adhering to that does lead to more clarity (and more verbosity) in cases such as this.  For example, "the plantations to which slaves were given" *vs* "the planattions given [to] slaves".

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I'm in my dotage, but with a degree in English. And I don't think I've ever encountered even an *antiquated* text genuinely promoting the "rule that sentences should not end with prepositions". But over a lifetime I must have heard and read *thousands* of instances of people ***mocking*** such an obviously ridiculous idea. Probably starting with my English teacher back in the 60s quoting the "rule" - then trotting out the ***...pedantic nonsense up with which I will not put**!* line usually attributed to Churchill taking issue with his proofreader's "corrections".

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with) provides this commentary: "Ending a sentence with a preposition (such as with, of, and to) is permissible in the English language. It seems that the idea that this should be avoided originated with writers Joshua Poole and John Dryden [....] **the idea that it is a rule is still held by many**."  That many do take it to be a rule (even if they are willing to flaunt it) correlates with my own experience.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Each to their own. If you *still* think ***up with which I will not put*** is "observing" rather than "flaunting a rule", I won't try any harder to convince you otherwise.

Comment: I'm not arguing for or against there being such a rule.  I'm arguing against the propositions that no such rule was ever promoted (it certainly was), and that no significant number of people believe it to be a rule (many certainly do).  But the original point was that whether it's accepted as a rule or not, these particular constructions ending with "to" might be clearer if revised so as not to do so.

Comment: Yawn. I never heard of Joshua Poole as an authority on English. But I do know most people today would have trouble understanding even John Dryden's *prose*, let alone his poetry! Nevertheless, I'd be interested in knowing exactly how he phrased his injunction. I imagine it's not easy to understand and remember whatever he wrote, or *surely* at least some pedants in the following centuries would have dressed it up for more modern consumption! But many people can cite the Churchill "refutation", even though that should be *very* hard to remember, being so obviously "unidiomatic".

Comment: [Found it!](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/SIEG/prepstranding.html) *Dryden wrote sniffily: ‘The preposition in the end of the sentence,’ ‘a common fault with him.’ (Later Dryden noticed that his own writing often had the same fault, so he set about fixing them up.) **But who had ever said it was a fault? Dryden provides no clue. It seems to have been just a whim of his.***

Comment: Actually, this is not a one-to-one *assignment* carried out by someone (like the absent DHCP server). The IP addresses are allocated, or *reserved* / *supplied* / *provided*, (by the standard) **for** the devices.

Comment: @Bergi: I have no idea what difference you're getting at. But if the allocated addresses are "reserved", that implies that *after* allocation, if you know the address, you know the corresponding device(s), and if you know the device, you know the corresponding address(es). Hence it makes no difference whether we say the addresses were assigned devices or the devices were assigned addresses. Anyway, that description works for me, even if it's not 100% accurate to circuit designers and systems programmers!

Comment: ...You'll note that in my example where the "direction" of assignment *does* matter, it's still the case that after the "gifting" / assignment / allocation (of slaves ***or*** plantations, howsoever it's parsed), if you know the slaves you know the plantation, and vice-versa, exactly as with OP's devices and addresses. The crucial difference is with the plantations example, it ***really*** matters who / what is ***owned*** by who / what!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I mean that a set of 65024 [link-local IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) is allocated (within [all available addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)) for use by the devices. Only once a device chooses (randomly) from this set, it does assign itself (to) that specific address.

Comment: In this case "allocated" has the same verb structure as "given" in your example? Is it natural for native speaker? I'm a non-native speaker, and I can understand the "given" example just fine, but same as OP, having trouble understanding the "allocated" example. I guess I just need to read more to familiarize with this use of that verb.

Comment: @justhalf: I may have overlooked something, but offhand I can't think of any relevant difference in the syntax of near-synonymous verbs ***allocate, assign, give, apportion, allot, earmark,...*** If you can understand *Give John the job* and *Assign the job to John* you're halfway there. You just need to get your head around things like *I need to allocate more workers to that job,* to see how we can often "invert" the syntactic roles of "agent" and "patient" (verb "subject" and "object") in such "one-to-one" relationships.

Comment: ...You have a number of devices and addresses, OR workers and jobs, OR whatever, that initially have ***no*** specific defined relationship individually. You "give, assign, allocate" one specific  device/address OR worker/job to  one specific address/device OR one specific job/worker, and generally speaking it doesn't make much difference which "direction" you make the connection - it's usually "the same" connection either way round.

Comment: ...but you could certainly look into how a verb like *to **link*** works. You can ask *What's the job John was allocated?* or *What's the address this device was given?* (with or without ***to*** at the end), but you *can't* drop the final preposition in *What's the address this device was **linked to**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you so much for your pedagogical examples! Really appreciate that. What's interesting is that in your last few examples, I can understand them just fine as well. Only the OP example sounds weird to me. I'm trying to hypothesize a few possibilities to explain this, but haven't found anything satisfying so far. The phrase *set of IP addresses [which are] allocated to the devices" is also fine to me (with and without the thing in bracket).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, no, because allocate can take a direct object. An address can be allocated a device, or a device can be allocated an address. Here, APIPA is allocating devices addresses.

The sentence is in the passive voice. So, the devices *are* allocated addresses, and it’s telling you which addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, definitely not, because in the subject domain, devices are not allocated to IP addresses; IP addresses are allocated to devices.

A clearer phrasing might be:

> APIPA is a set of IP addresses that are allocated to devices when the main DHCP server is not reachable

As written, it's fairly obscure syntax, albeit intelligible to most native speakers, where *devices* is the indirect object in the phrase "that devices are allocated" (the direct object is the word modified by the phrase, *addresses*).

Comment: Actually in this case, neither are allocated (assigned) *to* the other. Rather, the IP addresses are allocated (reserved) from the range of all address for the devices.